# On top of vs on bottom of

Tags: grammar

Why is it ok to say, "on top of the table", but not "on bottom of the table?" Is it ok? Was it ever considered ok?

Edit: To clarify, I'm asking about the missing "the", not about the fact that tables can hold things up better if the objects are on top of them...

Comment: Gravity, maybe?

Comment: There's a label on the bottom of the table that says where it was made.

Comment: One reason is that there’s a bottom of the table top, but the table really has legs. It does not have a bottom in the same way that a box does.

Comment: There's a label on THE bottom of the table...not a label on bottom of the table. (I'm asking about the THE)

Comment: This is actually an excellent question. I can think of no good answer at all, other than that this is just how it's come to be. We do say *on **the** table top* and *on **the** table bottom*, but we normally only say *on top of the table* and *on **the** bottom of the table*. While *on **the** top of the table* isn't ungrammatical, it sounds odd in most (although not all) contexts I can think of. But take note of this: both *paint on top of the table* and *paint on **the** top of the table* are used, and they can mean different things.

Comment: I'd argue it's the acceptance of *on top of* (without the article) that's more questionable than the lack of *on bottom of*.

Comment: Probably because ***on top of*** is a very common idiomatic expression used also figuratively, unlike “on bottom of“. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+top+of

Comment: @Hachi That does nothing to address the question of *why*. It just repeats my statement that it simply seems to be *just how it's come to be*. An idiom is just a *common saying*. Some things we can actually explain, but others we can't.

Comment: @JasonBassford - there is always  a reason, sometime we simply don’t know.

Comment: @Hachi I don't get your point. How does that help answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s due to “top” being used two ways.

“On top of” isn’t the analogous to “at the bottom of”. The analogue is “under”.

> The spoon is on top of the table.
>   The mat is under the table.

Those words refer to objects located outside the referenced item (table). “On top of” and “below” are both markers of relative position. In the case of “top”, it isn’t really referencing the highest portion of the table - it is talking about something higher than the whole table.

The analogue to “at the bottom of” is “at the top of”. These reference things in the same position as “the top” or “the bottom” of something. For example:

> The title is at the top of the list.
>   The ball is at the bottom of the well.

Here, “the” identifies a specific part of the item, and “top” and “bottom” are both parts of the respective objects.

Comment: The spoon is ‘on the table’, rather than ‘on top of the table’. I think the opposite of under the table is on or over the table.

Comment: @Hachi Hm, if contact is to be implied, perhaps we should use “on the underside of the table”.

Answer (score 0):

“Top” refers to the highest position, and “bottom” refers to the lowest position.

'On top of the building'  means 'on the roof' of the building'. But 'on the top of the building' refers to the highest floor.
However, in respect of table, we can say 'on the top of the table' or 'on top of the table' to mean the upper surface of the table.

A box has a bottom, a sea has a bottom. But does a table have a bottom (the lowest inner surface) like a container? But "on the bottom of the table" means 'on those parts of the table, which lie lower than its top surface" : There is a price sticker label on the bottom of the table. But the expression, ''on bottom of" is unidiomatic, and such usage is normally found nowhere.

However, we can also use 'on the table top', 'on the table bottom'.